# Why do I need to hit enter to get my shell prompt after my init.d script completes?

Tags: ssh, centos, shell-script, init-script

I had to write my own CentOS init.d script for [celery](http://ask.github.com/celery/index.html) because it only ships with one for Debian. You can see the script I wrote when I answered my own stack overflow question [3989656](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3989656/init-d-celery-script-for-centos).

But there's a problem with this script. if I invoke it:

```
sudo service celeryd start
```

then I need to hit enter to get a shell prompt after it completes. This is a problem because  I want to invoke it via ssh from another machine by doing:

```
ssh 192.168.2.3 sudo service celeryd start
```

and ssh never returns. (I use [fabric](http://docs.fabfile.org/0.9.3/) to start and stop remote services, and this hangs it because it invokes the ssh command above).

What would cause this behavior, and how do I fix it in my script?

Note that if I do "sh -x /etc/init.d/celeryd" as recommended by Thomas Themel in the comments, the output is:

```
runuser -s /bin/bash - apache -c 'ulimit -S -c 0 >/dev/null 2>&1 ; /usr/local/django/portalapps/manage.py celeryd --pidfile /var/run/celery.pid -f /var/log/celeryd.log -l INFO'
```

I don't understand how the daemon function in /etc/init.d/functions (which is what produces this series of bash commands) actually daemonizes the process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had the exact same problem - your question and investigations actually helped me find the answer.

Start celery with `celery_detach` - and, poof! Things work!

ie. `manage.py celery_detach --params --settings=foo`

It returns immediately, with a proper line break, and the things that fabric is looking for.

Answer (score 5):

You might actually have a shell prompt and not realize it. If you have a program that writes to the terminal while in the background, your prompt gets covered up, but it's still ready for input.

test.sh:

```
#! /bin/sh
echo -e "This is a test\n\n"
```

interactive shell:

```
$sh test.sh &
$This is a test



_
```

In this example, the prompt is there. You see the "$" right before "This is a test" that is the prompt. At the bottom you can see the cursor waiting for input. If you type a command here and press enter, it will work as usual. Try running `ls` after starting your daemon but before pressing `<enter>`.

Comment: I second that, happen to me sometime.

Comment: I don't think it's that since it doesn't explain the caller's "ssh never returns" description.

Answer (score 3):

You might want to figure out what exactly eats that return, by first running the /etc/init.d script directly with (sudo as required) `sh -x /etc/init.d/celeryd start`. If it is in the shell script, you should see it this way. If `daemon` itself is waiting for a newline before returning, your answer will be celeryd specific and might benefit from running it through `strace` or simply with a `< /dev/null` appended so that it doesn't have access to standard input through your terminal.

Another "grope in the dark" thing to try: run `ssh` with the `-nt` option to disable terminal allocation and standard input.

Comment: I've modified the original question to show the output when running with "-x". I think the celeryd program ("manage.py celeryd") runs in the foreground, and doesn't accept any input while it's running. I assumed that the "daemon" function would do the appropriate stuff to run it as a daemon, but it's not clear to me how it does this.

Answer (score 0):

Does the `daemon` command need a `&` at the end. I don't think it does. This may be the source of your problem.

Comment: I added it as a workaround because I encountered this problem, but it didn't fix it.

Comment: @lorin: Another thing I noticed is that `CELERYD` is not getting set, but I assume it is in `/etc/default/celeryd`.

Comment: Yup, this is set in /etc/default/celeryd, like so: CELERYD="/usr/local/django/portalapps/manage.py celeryd --pidfile $CELERYD_PIDFILE"