# How do I get the prompt back when running `at' from terminal

Tags: shell-script, terminal, at

Perhaps this is more of a general question on scripting and terminal use than of the use of the `at' command. Regardless, I am exploring the use of the at command to get a handle on its behavior and how I can control it before I use it for a serious script.

I wrote a trivial script named at-test.sh, saved it to $HOME and made it executable:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo $(date +%H:%M:%s) > /dev/pts/9
exit 0
```

then ran it via

```
at -f './at-test.sh' now + 1 minutes
```

It runs as expected, but I must Ctrl+C to get the shell prompt back. I later learned that the Enter key would work also to get the prompt back.
Is there anyway to get the prompt back via a command in the script?

Comment: That's odd. `at` should immediately go to the background. What version of `at` is this (`at -V`)? What operating system? If Enter works, what else do you need?

Comment: @terdon - at version 3.1.14 running on LinuxMint 17. I just read this [link] (https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/4230/340857) which is exactly what is happening. I guess it is of no consequence really, I just thought it was odd behavior. My ultimate plan is to use it to end public computer sessions by timing out, then forcing logoff, so that behavior is probably ok.

Answer (score 2):

You've successfully submitted the `at` job and it has successfully printed the date to (your) terminal at `/dev/pts/9`. You also have a shell there that has printed a prompt and is duly waiting for your input.

This is a simulation of what happened:

```
your-prompt-here$ at -f './at-test.sh' now + 1 minutes
job 1 at Fri Mar  8 20:13:00 2019
your-prompt-here$
```

## ... one minute passes; resume the demonstration

```
your-prompt-here$ 20:14:1552093897
echo I am still here
I am still here
your-prompt-here$
```

As you can see, my shell accepted the `echo` command; my cursor simply wasn't where I "expected" it to be because the `at` job scribbled onto my terminal.